# Differential equation of plane rotator

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, quantum-mechanics

Just reflecting.

I'm studying plane rotator. My Teacher and my book say that the solution of $ -{\hbar^2 \over {2I}}   {d^2\over{dx^2}} \psi_n(\phi)=E_n\psi$

is

$\psi_n(\phi)= C e^ {i\pm {\sqrt {2IE \over\hbar^2}}\phi}$.

Shouldn't the solution be in this form?

$\psi_n(\phi)= C_1 e^ {i {\sqrt {2IE_n \over\hbar^2}}\phi} +C_2 e^ {-i {\sqrt {2IE_n \over\hbar^2}}\phi} $.

I'm sure I'm just confused at the moment but I can't see the reason.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/522212/83835. That's not a complete answer, but it might help a bit.

Comment: Perhaps it's just poor notation. Is it possible that the solution is supposed to say $i\times \pm \cdots$ instead of just $i\pm\cdots$? If that were the case, then the solutions would be the same.